# RestTemplate Post Request With an Addition Parameter Outside

Tags: android, post, resttemplate

How to Send post request using `resttemplate` in android in the following format?

```
{"UserInfo":{"Password":"TEST99","UserName":"TEST99"}}
```

hope to get a reply soon.

Answer (score 0):

You should add something like this while sending request

```
public static final MediaType JSON
    = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

and this well while making RequestBody

```
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
```

I think basically you want to convert encoding type to JSON.

Comment: public class UserInfo  {
    public String UserName;

    public String Password;

    public UserInfo(){
        UserName="";
        Password="";

    }

    public UserInfo( String UserName,String Password) {

        this.UserName=UserName;
        this.Password=Password;

}

Comment: I tried creating class its calling username and paswd proper but not outerUserinfo

Answer (score 0):

Code you interface like this

```
 @POST("yoururl")
Call<ResponseClass> someMethodName(@Body Example example );
```

Where You need to send Example class object and you can get Example clss by posting you jSON in http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: Can you please explain more clearly @Geethakrishna Juluri thanku